# Вывод названия папок архива

Tags: powershell

Хочу написать выражение, которые выводит только названия папок верхнего уровня из архива, но пока выводить только все содержимое.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

```
$x = & 'c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' l -slt D:\2.zip
$a = $x | Where-object {$_ -match '^path' }
$a
```

Получаю сейчас ответ типа

```
Path = D:\2.zip
Path = 1
Path = 1234.txt
Path = 2
Path = 2\123.txt
Path = 3
Path = 4
Path = 4\132131.txt
Path = 4\41
Path = 4\41\141
```

А хочу, чтобы

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$a` массив строк, так что единственный способ это обрезать их:

```
$x = & 'c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' l -slt C:\test\res_2.zip | Where-object {$_ -match '^path' } | ForEach-Object { $a += ($_.Replace('Path = ','')) }
$a
```